# How to refresh a div on a page with out reloading

Tags: ajax, partial-page-refresh

In my table I have results that come from a database and when I click on a link in the table to delete it,I am trying to get the table to refresh with out reloading the page. In the code below It works but I still have to refresh the entire page to be able to click on another link. STUCK!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('td a').click(function(){
            //alert($(this).attr('id'));
            var id =$(this).attr('id');
            var img_name =$(this).attr('name');
            //alert(img_name);

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "remove.php",
            cache: false,
            data: "id="+ id +"&img_name="+ img_name,
            success: function(message){
              alert(message);
           }
        });

        var url = "delete.inc.php"; //create random number

          setTimeout(function() {
         $("#table").load(url+" #table>*");
           }, 1000); //wait one second to run function
        /////////////////////// 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your click event is bound to 'td a' which is removed and replaced once the table is reloaded. As a result it will only ever work once. You need to setup your click event every time you reload your table.

I would suggest creating a separate function for your ajax request. Then setup your click event in your $(document).ready...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td a').click( function_name );
});
```

And also set it up in your success function...

```
...
success: function(message){
    alert(message);
    $('td a').click( function_name );
}
...
```

Comment: I am new to jquery and not real sure what you mean. I would really appreciate some more help,thanks